# Finger Swipe On iPad Screen

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad, swipe

How do i implement and code for recognizing swipes across the screen, and also making it so that if it swipes on a uiimageview then things happen, // code, how can i do this? THanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use UISwipeGestureRecognizer. Something like this to detect a swipe on `imageView`:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageSwiped:)];
swipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:swipe];
[swipe release];
```

Then define a method `- (void)imageSwiped:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender` and react to the swipe there.

Comment: but one more question, what if it can be any direction, should I use this operater: ||

Comment: You shoudln't use || ! `UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection` is enum composed by bit shited numbers. So you can combine but using the bit OR operator, which is | (single).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a `UISwipeGestureRecongizer` for it, unless you have a very specific gesture to recongize.

Try reading out : [Event Handling Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH6-SW1) from Apple.